# Use of IF and SET in the same SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to mix IF and SET statements in an SQL stored procedure.
I have already declared the variables p1, so,ct,ac, yoyo1,yoyo2, etc.). I would like to achieve the following results:

- if `so=0` then `p1=yoyo1` AND `so` becomes equal to `1`
- otherwise if `ct=0` then `p1=yoyo2` AND `ct` becomes equal to `1`
- otherwise if `ac=0` then `p1=yoyo3` AND `ac` becomes equal to `1`.

**I have tried the following SQL code but it returns `0`:**

```
SET p1=IF(so=0, yoyo1 AND SET so=1, 
  IF(ct=0, yoyo2 AND SET ct=1, 
     IF(ac=0 , yoyo3 AND SET ac=1,'image01.jpg')));
```

Comment: I believe you need Stored Procedure to accomplish such task.

Comment: Yes, this an excerpt of a stored procedure.

Comment: In SQL `IF` is a function, in TSQL - it's a statement.  You seem to be mixing them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is part of a stored procedure, you can use **[MySQL `IF` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html)** as follows :

```
IF so=0 THEN 
    SET p1 = 'yoyo1';
    SET so = 1;
ELSEIF ct = 0 THEN
    SET p1 = 'yoyo2';
    SET ct = 1;
ELSEIF ac = 0 THEN
    SET p1 = 'yoyo3';
    SET ac = 1;
ELSE
    SET p1 = 'image01.jpg';
END IF;
```

As explained in the documentation, beware not to mix *the `IF` statement* (the ternary operator) with *the `IF()` function*, wich is a control flow function.

Comment: **I have used your example:**

    IF so=0 THEN SET p1='yoyo1'; SET so=1; 
    ELSEIF ct=0 THEN p1='yoyo2'; SET ct=1 ;
    ELSEIF ac=0 THEN p1='yoyo3' ; SET ac=1 ;
    ELSEIF p1='image01.jpg'; 
    END IF ; 
**But I get a syntax error message:** 

_MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'so=0 THEN SET p1=yoyo1; SET so=1; ELSEIF ct=0 THEN p1=yoyo2; SET ct=' at line 55_

Comment: There was a typo on `ELSIF` instead of `ELSEIF` but it looks like you already spotted it.

Comment: This is compiling OK on MySQL v5.5 to 8.0 **[in this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vXrz9V72A3LzXtvESfiPTw/1)**

Comment: In the error message you showed, there are missing single quotes around `yoyo` words : eg `SET p1=yoyo1` should be `SET p1='yoyo1'`

Comment: Thank you GMB. The whole code is comprised within a WHILE DO statement should parentheses be added?

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria : mm, no I don't think that parentheses are needed.

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria : if my answer was helpful to you and solved your problem, please upvote/accept it... Thanks !

Comment: Could you please update your fiddle with the final statement: p1='image01.jpg' ("if none of the above IF is true"); thank you.

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria : I updated my answer. Feel free to use the fiddle as you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
    IF so=0 THEN
        SET p1='yoyo';
        SET so=1;
    ELSE
        IF ct=0 THEN
            SET p1='yoyo2';
            SET ct=1;
        ELSE
            IF ac=0 THEN
                SET p1='yoyo3';
                SET ac=1;
            ELSE
                SET p1='image01.jpg';
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
```

OR use [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) (I'd prefer this one):

```
    CASE
        WHEN so=0 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET p1='yoyo';
                SET so=1;
            END;
        WHEN ct=0 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET p1='yoyo2';
                SET ct=1;
            END;
        WHEN ac=0 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET p1='yoyo3';
                SET ac=1;
            END;
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET p1='image01.jpg';
            END;
    END CASE;
```